# Is there a Japanese word for "Easter holidays"?

Tags: english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

I was wondering if there is a Japanese word for "Easter holidays"? While I am aware that most of Japan does not celebrate Easter, I was surprised to find a word for Easter (復活祭, fukkatsusai). My guess is that would make "Easter holidays" 復活祭休み, fukkatsusaiyasumi, but I couldn't find any reference of that being an actual word.

So: Does Japanese have a word for "Easter holidays"? I am also interested in a loan word, but even more interested if there is a "genuine" japanese word for that.

Comment: Whilst individual Christians may celebrate Easter, Japan as a whole does not and there are no official holidays for it, so I'd be surprised if there was a "genuine" Japanese word.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have mentioned that: I am aware that most of Japan does not celebrate Easter, of course. But I was surprised to find 復活祭, and so I figured there might be a word for Easter holidays as well.

Comment: Fair enough. Probably worth editing that into your main question.

Comment: makes sense, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ask Google, イースター休暇 is arguably the most dominant way to refer to Easter holidays, including many expat blogs and information websites like [this](https://tokuhain.arukikata.co.jp/copenhagen/2011/04/post_51.html) (a guidebook compared to *Lonely Planet* in English).

However, 復活祭（節）休み, イースター休み would be understood without any strange feeling too, even though it might be a word most people have heard for the first time. Likewise you can say 感謝祭休み (Thanksgiving), ノウルーズ休み (Nowruz) or 旧正月休み (Lunar New Year). As also mentioned in a comment, I don't think there is a common Japanese name for Easter holidays, because such custom has not taken root in Japan.

By the way, finding Christian words translated in Japanese is not an uncommon thing. People in Meiji who studied Western knowledge naturally learned a lot about Christianity. As a result, we say [豚に真珠](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B1%9A%E3%81%AB%E7%9C%9F%E7%8F%A0) or [目から鱗](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E9%B1%97).